# How can I fix the gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, uninstall, re-installation

I am using gnome-shell on Ubuntu 11.10. After I installed some of the extensions, whenever it logs in; it would not show the userbar (the one with the clock etc). I tried doing the following:

[How to remove and reinstall GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67764/how-to-remove-and-reinstall-gnome-3)

But it just doesn't work. Obviously uninstalling will work, but I would like to be able to use the gnome-shell, and not completely remove it - as soon as I install it again; the same problem persists. The userbar does not show up, I just get the background image, and no GUI at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove extensions by going to `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and removing what you've installed.

On a somewhat related note, I just got into a situation like yours where the user bar wouldn't show up, but I had NO extensions loaded, and un-installing and reinstalling gnome-shell made no difference.

I actually reinstalled Ubuntu (this being 11.10), but used the option to not format the drive.  It completely reinstalled the O/S, reinstalled the packages I'd installed since installation, and left my home directory intact (yes, I did have a backup available, but didn't need to use it).  And now gnome-shell works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Open gnome-tweak-tool, or install it first using the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`.

Open it and there you can view your extensions and deactivate them to see if that's the problem.