# Minimize, Maximize and Close icons are not displayed on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, icons, 20.04

I updated to ubuntu 20.04 and my maximize, minimize and close icons are gone. And the settings app is crashing.
This is my firefox
[image: firefox]
This is settings
[image: settings]

**Edit:** I changed the theme to adwaita dark and settings works again
[image: dark settings]
P.S. Firefox still doesn't work but hovering over buttons shades them
[image: dark firefox]

**Edit 2:** Installed xfce and everything is working. I will try reinstalling gnome when I am bored with xfce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re installing gnome-shell worked. Though I lost all my extentions. For more information on how to do that, check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67764/how-to-remove-and-reinstall-gnome-3)