# Title bar buttons (close, minimize, maximize) apper in system status on top bar Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome 3.36.8

Tags: gnome, dconf, window-buttons, top-bar, gnome-tweaks

I have been getting this

[image]

Although I have installed both dconf-editor and gnome tweaks, I try to use dconf-editor only for features not present in gnome tweaks. I used gnome-tweaks to make sure the workspace spans multiple screens. I also used it to change which side these title bar icons a bit by switching them to left but I switched them back again to the right. I used dconf just for making sure the alt-` works only for windows in a workspace. I also followed the reset instructions explained in [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168006/no-title-bar-button-to-close-window-ubuntu-18-04)

Just wanted to confirm if there's an alternative to reinstalling gnome [like this case.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237553/minimize-maximize-and-close-icons-are-not-displayed-on-ubuntu-20-04)

---

**Software versions:**

1. Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
2. Gnome 3.36.8
3. Gnome Tweaks
   a. Gnome Tweaks version 3.34.0
   b. GNOME Shell 3.36.7 (ubuntu mode)
   c. GTK 3.24.20
4. Dconf editor 3.36.0

---

Answer (score 0):

Disable all your custom installed extensions. Log out then back in. Then reenable your Gnome Shell extensions one by one, using Tweaks. Each time check whether the window control buttons have reappeared. This procedure will allow you to identify the extension causing this effect. Then it is up to you to either continue using it or not.