# Ubuntu 20.04 "Oh No! Something has gone wrong and the system can't recover" error on login

Tags: 20.04, login

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for several days and then at one point when I tried to login I was met with a "Oh No! Something has gone wrong and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again." message and if I clicked it, it sent me back to the login screen. In addition to this screen I also had access to my terminal, I think because I have it setup to open on login. Rebooting did not help.

I'm a noob to linux so I'm going to list everything I tried even if some of it isn't relevant. Sorry for the long post.

The only "big" thing I remember doing before I logged out/ shutdown my computer before I started getting these messages was I installed [this](https://github.com/petRUShka/vim-opencl) vim plugin to enable opencl syntax highlighting by git cloning it in `~/.vim/pack/plugins/start` the syntax highlighting was working fine before I logged out. I was able to remove the `~/.vim/` and `~/.vimrc` files from my home directory but it did not help.

Then I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239025/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-oh-no-something-went-wrong) solution by doing

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove && sudo reboot
```

It worked without any problems but I still could not login.

I had installed rocm opencl previously by following [this](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html#supported-operating-systems) installation guide, and it was working fine, but I thought maybe this could be causing some problems for some reason, so I uninstalled it from the same guide. Some of the directories weren't removed because they had stuff in them so i manually removed the last few directories in `/opt/rocm` so now my `/opt` directory is empty. This still did not fix my problem.

From [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/oh-no-something-has-gone-wrong-on-restart-4175510641/) post I found out that maybe logging in as a different user could work. So I created a new test user and logged in and it worked! I think this means that my problem is with my main user configuration and not with my system but idk. From this test user I `su - main` to my main account and tried to reinstall gnome following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67764/how-to-remove-and-reinstall-gnome-3) post, because I read somewhere that this might help so first I did:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell
```

which still gave me the error message on my main user account when I tried logging in, so then I tried:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell
sudo apt install gnome-shell
```

This still did not fix my issue when I tried logging in with my main account but now when I log in with my test account the dock on the left side is hidden by default, and I can only access it with the windows key or by pressing activities in the top left. I made a test2 account to see what would happen and again the dock was hidden. I am currently writing this from my test2 account.

The next thing I was going to try was to remove configuration files in my main account and see what happens but I'm not sure what I should remove and how to do this safely and if this is even a good idea at all.

I am not opposed to backing up my files and reinstalling ubuntu because I have only been using it for a few days and I need to reinstall rocm opencl again either way. However, I would still like to know what happened and if there is a way to fix it so that this doesn't happen again (and if it does so I know how to fix it) when I would be more opposed to reinstalling ubuntu in the future.

Sorry for the long post, I really appreciate you taking the time to read it.

Edit: I decided to just create a new admin account and remove my old one and reconfigure everything. So far there have been no login issues or anything. I was also able to get the dock to appear again by doing: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`
Thanks for all your help everyone I couldn't have done it without you!

Comment: Is your package management in a consistent state? Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and see if there are any error messages.

Comment: @Jos `sudo apt udate` says all packages are up to date so `sudo apt upgrade` doesn't install or update anything

Comment: I have same too. any help?

Comment: @Sadegh See my edit, but my solution was to just create a new account and move all my data and configuration settings to it

Comment: Congrats on solving the problem. It would be clearer for others if you added your resolution as an answer and accepted it.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, debugging it since yesterday.

Creating another user did work as a temporary fix.
So it really seems like some configuration issue.

Renaming / removing "~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extension-updates" (or "~/.local/share/gnome-shell") and trying to log back in fixed it for me.
(I have to double-check later, as I'm currently accessing my desktop via RDP)

The folder itself contained only "extension-list@tu.berry", which seems to be the offending extension.

According to the [Gnome extensions page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3088/extension-list/), there appears to be someone else who experienced issues with this extension as of yesterday. I'll contact the dev later if I find the time to do so and I don't forget about it.